# Help with 之，間，於

Tags: translation

衛福編編報報 發文時間：2021.10.14
台積電、鴻海永齡、慈濟三間企業和民間團體捐贈之第八批BNT疫苗82.7萬劑於10月14日上午抵臺

Is this translation correct?

Weifu edited report, publish date: 2021.10.14

The eighth batch of 827,000 BNT doses donated by TSMC, FoxConn Yong-Ling, Tzu Chi, and private organizations arrived on the morning of 10/14.

I remember that 之 is equivalent to 的 in writing — is that the correct interpretation here?

間 = does this mean among?
於 = does this mean on?

Comment: The last character “臺” is the abbreviation of “臺灣”, so the translation should be "...arrived in Taiwan on the morning of 10/14"

Answer (score 1):

The eighth batch of 827,000 BNT doses donated by **the three enterprises** - TSMC, FoxConn Yong-Ling, Tzu Chi, and **other** private organizations has arrived **in Taiwan** on the morning of 10/14.

之 = 的

於 = on, at, in

間 = does this mean among? Yes, it can also mean between (兩者之間), in the middle (中間), a descriptive space (人間/世間/陰間/陽間/隔間/裡間/外間/偏間), in here 間 = 家 (兩間工廠/ㄧ間雜貨店).